# C++: Is it worth using static_cast to avoid if conditions which compare numbers?

Tags: c++, if-statement, static-cast

I try to make very time efficient code in C++. I was told that I should avoid if conditions whenever possible. So I was thinking that type conversion could do the job. The code with if condition would look like this:

```
double a = .512;  // some real number
double x = 1.1;  // a coordinate that gets changed when if condition is true
a *= a;  // a squared
if(a >= 1){x += .1;}
```

I would avoid the if condition in the following way.

```
double a = .512;  // some real number
double x = 1.1;  // a coordinate that gets changed when if condition is true
a *= a;  // a squared
x += static_cast<bool>(static_cast<int>(a)) * .1
```

This first converts `a` into an `int`. This gives `0` for `a<1` and a non-zero `int` for `a>1`. The second conversion then converts all non-zero `int`s to `true`.
But is it really faster? Are there any problems I could run into using this method?

Comment: Profile, examine, optimize. Throwing away half of the language before you even know where the bottleneck is is pointless.

Comment: "But is it really faster?" profile

Comment: How will your solution deal with negative numbers, infinities, and NaN? Unless you're really counting instructions, it's usually better to write the clearest possible code and let the compiler perform such micro-optimisations where helpful.

Comment: @amon a^2 cannot be negative...

Comment: Your second code is unreadable, does this microoptimization worse it?

Comment: @Slava fair enough, but what about infinities and NaNs? :p

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having the `if` statement where needed. Unlike some other languages, C++ does not rely on one-liners that much.

Comment: @Quentin to be frankly I do not know what `a >= 1` will do with NaN and infinities :(

Comment: "I was told that I should avoid if conditions whenever possible." I think this is a really bad advise. Write readable code, profile and optimize. Make such optimizations only it is really necessary or your program will become unmaintanable very fast.

Comment: @Slava Any comparison involving a `NaN` is `false` except for `operator!=` which is always `true` (even with itself). At least, for IEEE 754 conforming implementations. And I would assume infinity is greater than 1.

Comment: Plus the difference in performance most likely depends on given cpu and/or compiler.

Comment: Please, please, please don't obfuscate your code just to avoid using one language construct or another. Write clear easy to read code, then profile it and *if* and *only if* there is a performance problem start thinking about how to change it. And *always* use an optimized build when profiling.

Comment: @Moritz "*This gives `0` for `a<1`*" - maybe in this specific case, but in general only if `a` truncated to int is EXACTLY `0`.  *ANY* non-zero value, including negatives, will be `true` when interpreted as a `bool`, which might not give you the same result as the original code. You probably meant to use something more like this instead: `x += static_cast<int>(a >= 1.0) * .1;`, where `true` is 1 and `false` is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not bother optimizing your code in this way. If you are using a reliable up-to-date compiler there are only two ways it can go.

- You will mess up and write code that is not strictly equivalent because you missed an edge case or you accidentally caused undefined behavior.
- If the code is equivalent, it is going to get compiled to the same instructions anyway.

In your case, the conversion is not equivalent. According to the standard ([cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)):

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. **If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined** (even when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply). If the destination type is bool, this is a boolean conversion (see below).

Values that are too large, NaN and infinity are all problems in your version.

Regarding performance they should be similar. Using GCC 7.3 on godbolt ([link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAckziARk2wBqAGZi2qCPLFLVLcit36VADwCUKrgHYBABgCCKlypYqAVFwDMAETc%2BfC4A9MFuKsIAjmIspNiYXE6uKgRqEO4%2BuD7%2B9Ba2fGbW/NkqAHT0gba%2Bic6ucUQSbOaVTlU1NTIWzLIArDLkbLL2/eiyAMKCghHikqq83vT9REOdXQDWID323TIALP0AtpvbgzLD5KMy/cIg28tnneRwsCgYOPjEZJTUdDzM7JxJvwRDMpLITMp1JptBCDEZYeYrPkasl3F4/AFvEEVKFwlEYnEEklXIVJhjhEQWEQCKgAPqoFgUnxjBTodBMTIQClUmn0xlEZkENgC7y4dIWKweMoVLEourYBqkJpmFqOKqPJi9fqnc6XCbFfjTCRSIreHhLFYS8hIbAsHCkahdTV7Q7HAYrC6ya63cj3YZWjbebylIOhsPhgBsO282o9lwtDy6zwQ8Agr3QBwADgRlBQqBAMFmc9gHcAbN5yGoc0QSzcIAoPQohbEAJ6yRbkQsHbDCgDybCYbYe5BwBwByg9hDiqGpADdsDdh9gzNhUGIa%2B3%2BkKa87zkwCApSK2xlhpDIO0RSAQjon/hw0EChPuFDdIF10Jnqeg2IvrqDpLkOx9O6w6XGYAAcEYALQRrsKjAKgqAqDYIYqBAHwkKQpqMCoJ5Frm2FWPqAj8Am/pdDadolo6Oz7OQRxbCBupeiIPp%2Bo8yZpmgGbZrm3wFjxxaluWlbVrW1ANsOTZsK2m6dhm3Z9gOQ7nKO45nqpBDTnOC4esuq7rmeHbbtgu79M%2BR6kC2J44HJl7Xpad6AgaT4Hq%2BEDvp%2BBDfr%2BILGtIPBOlqTEjLIEHQbB8GIchqHoYQmGmn8uGCQR8yBbhj5kas1q2vaNEbIxzp0QxJxxixNx3Ja6wgEGIbhvVQZRs6MYhZ6Vy%2Bo5nEoIQahqPxTBIDcjCkINICBUBsagbIvipGo5iQTBcEIUhKHeCos7CPNEVLdFq1ZQGNXBg1DW0ZNzHtRVHWJkFMjmq18ZXeR5DzqQwjeYMuxAA%3D)), the assembly is not identical, but they both contain one conditional jump, which is what you hoped to avoid by removing the `if` condition.